# Granting Access For Blogger in OAUTH 2

Tags: php, blogger

I am new to Google Oauth 2.I saw google documentation and got the below php library

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application'); 
$client->setClientId('...');
$client->setClientSecret('....');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://photoapp.biz/0/blogger/test.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('....');
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');
  print 'Your Activities: <pre>' . print_r($activities, true) . '</pre>';

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}

?>
```

From above code My authentication works fine and i am able to get the Token.But This code allows access for Google Plus .I need To authenticat Blogger with Oauth.Google documentation did not help me.Can some one please guide me .Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking for it